# How to convert yard value to meter value in angularjs

Tags: html, angularjs, valueconverter

Here am Trying to convert the meter value to yard. I have two dropdowns. First dropdown has some values. And the 2nd dropdown has two values "meter" & "yard", Now the question is If the **meter** selected from the 2nd dropdown, The values in the first dropdown want to remain same. But, If **"Yard"** selected the entire values from the first dropdown needs to be convert into Yard values. I found the logic but i dont know how implement it into angular controller. Here am created a plunkr https://plnkr.co/edit/Q4lxXf6YRrdAV2kUNAln?p=preview

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.6.2" data-semver="1.6.2" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.2/angular.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
   <div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">

 <select class="form-control" ng-model="distancetypeId" ng-options="Distance.id as Distance.value for Distance in data"></select>
<select class="form-control" ng-model="ConverttypeId" ng-options="Convert.id as Convert.type for Convert in convertor" ng-change="convertToMeter()"></select>

</div>
  </body>

</html>
```

AngularJS

```
angular.module("app",[])
.controller("ctrl",function($scope){


    $scope.data = [{
    "id": 1,
    "value": 254
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "value": 100
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "value":250 
  },
  {
    "id": 4,
    "value":10 
  }]

    $scope.convertor = [{
    "id": 1,
    "type": "Meter"
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "type": "Yard"
  }];



 $scope.convertToMeter=function(ConverttypeId){
           if(ConverttypeId = 2){

    //this is logic that i want to do  (dropdown1values=value*1.0936;)

 }}

 });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So if **Yard** is selected then you need to multiply the distance value by 1.0936 so you can directly do this in the `ngOptions` like this :

```
ng-options="Distance.id as (Distance.value * (1 + (ConverttypeId == '2') * 0.0936)) for Distance in data"
```

So if `Converttypeid` equals to `'2'` (which means that Yard option is selected) then the distance is multiplyed by `1 + (true * 0.0936)` which equals to `1.0936`.

If not the distance is multiplyed by `1 + (false * 0.0936)` which equals to `1`, so it's still the same value.

[Here is a plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/Tvb5jg5g7NflBfXRaJe2?p=preview) to show this

Answer (score 1):

you can modify the `ng-change` function like this

```
 $scope.convertToMeter=function( ){
    if($scope.ConverttypeId == 2){
    // document.getElementById("outputMeters").innerHTML=value/1.0936;
      for(var i=0; i<=$scope.data.length-1; i++){
        $scope.data[i].value =( $scope.data[i].value/ 0.9144 ).toFixed(2)
      }
    }else if($scope.ConverttypeId == 1){
      for(var i=0; i<=$scope.data.length-1; i++){
        $scope.data[i].value = parseInt($scope.data[i].value * 0.9144) 
      }
    }

 }
```

[Demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/xPrOWlKJN9R5Vk3xlsiq?p=preview)